# Is it possible to find $h$ hermitian metric such that $Isom_{h}(X) \cong Aut(X)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, hermitian

I suspect this is true for some class of analytic manifolds (Riemann surfaces maybe), but  my knowledge in differential geometry is very poor, so I could not conclude it. For complex manifolds, is it possible to find $h$ hermitian metric such that $Isom_{h}(X) \cong Aut(X)$ (where $Isom_{h}(X)$ means the isometries of $h$ that preserves orientation)? What are the obstructions? Any ideas on how to measure this? Is this true at least for Riemann surfaces?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** As a friend of mine has just suggested, what about the complexification $Isom_{h}(X)^{\mathbb{C}}$? Will $Isom_{h}(X)^{\mathbb{C}} \cong Aut(X)$ for some special class of complex manifolds?

Comment: By $\mathrm{Isom}_h(X)$, do *you* mean only the *holomorphic* isometries of $h$, as Liviu wants it to mean?  Assuming this, I think that an appropriate hypothesis on $X$ might be that the isotropy group $\mathrm{Aut}(X,p)\subset \mathrm{Aut}(X)$ should be compact for each $p\in X$. This is clearly necessary and may even be sufficient.  You don't actually need that $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ itself be compact, as the example of the punctured complex plane shows. Note that this hypothesis can hold at some points and not others; for example, consider $\mathbb{CP}^2$ blown up at three non-collinear points.

Comment: @RobertBryant Yes, holomorphic isometries. I forgot to put that they must preserve orientation.

Comment: Well, orientation, by itself, is not enough.  You can have orientation preserving isometries (in higher dimensions) that are still not complex linear.

Comment: @RobertBryant thanks for the observation, I have never heard about this, do you know some example?

Comment: Sure, start with an elliptic curve $C$ with an anti-holomorphic isometry $\tau:C\to C$.  Of course, $\tau$ does not preserve orientation, but $\tau\times\tau:C\times C\to C\times C$ *does* preserve orientation and is not holomorphic.  About your edit for the complexified isometry group:  That won't always be possible either; just look at the Poincaré disk.  (Of course, it will *sometimes* be possible, but it won't always.)

Comment: @RobertBryant Ok, thanks, but do you know whether there is some exact sequence (or some cohomological related stuff) such that the automorphisms group or the isometry group appears? In this case, I could try to find some obstruction.

Answer (score 3):

The group of isometries of a compact Riemann manifold  is a  *compact* Lie group. Thus if  $X$ is compact and $G={\rm Aut}\;(X)$ is not compact, then  you cannot choose such a metric. On the other hand, if  $G$ is compact you can produce such a metric  by  averaging with respect to an invariant probability measure on $G$.

**Edit.** As Robert Bryant  indicated in his comment I have to be more careful.  If $(X,h)$ is a complex hermitian manifold, then $\DeclareMathOperator{\Isom}{Isom}$ by $\Isom_h(X)$ I understand the group of  biholomorphic maps $F: X\to X$ such that $F^*h=h$.

Comment: You do have to be a tad more careful, though:  It's conceivable (and, in fact, there are examples) of $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$-invariant hermitian metrics on $X$ for which the isometry group is larger than $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$, so you do have to make sure that your metric doesn't have any 'extra' isomorphisms if you are going to get equality, which the OP wanted.

Comment: @  Robert You are absolutely correct.    I tacitly assumed  that  in the holomorphic category an isometry   is a biholomorphic map.

Answer (score 2):

No. Check the Riemann sphere or any elliptic curve, or a punctured complex plane, or a complex plane. Otherwise yes (on Riemann surfaces), by the uniformization theorem.

Comment: More examples: Grassmannians, projective spaces, complex Euclidean spaces. The automorphism group of projective space is the projectivized special linear group, while the isometry group is the projectivized unitary group.

Comment: The biholomorphism group of $\mathbb{C}^2$ contains beasts like $(z,w) \mapsto (z,w+f(z))$ for any entire holomorphic function $f(z)$: far from preserving any metric, since the stabilizer of a point is infinite dimensional and not compact.

Comment: What about the complexification of $Isom_h (X)$? In the first case, it will hold.

Comment: Try $\mathbb{C}^2$; the complexification of the isometry group is the complex affine group, finite dimensional, while the biholomorphism group is infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is so, sometimes. The prime example in the unit disc $|z|<1$ in the complex plane. This is a $1$-dimensional complex analytic manifold. Its automorphism group is
a $3$-parametric group which is isomorphic to $PSL_2(R)$.
In the unit disc there is a Riemannian metric, which is called the Poincare metric
and for which the isometries are exactly the automorphisms.

Now by the uniformization theorem, almost all Riemann surfaces have the unit disc
as the universal cover. It follows that for almost all Riemann surfaces there is such a metric, that your equality holds. It is called the hyperbolic metric. (Exceptional Riemann  surfaces are the sphere, the plane
the punctured plane and the complex $1$-parametric family of tori.)

Some of this extends to complex manifolds in higher dimension. The analog of the hyperbolic
metric is called the Kobayashi metric, and it is believed that "most" complex manifolds 
have it, though this is difficult to prove in sprecific cases. Moreover, Kobayashi metric
is frequently not a Riemannian (Hermirtian) metric but only a Finsler metric.
Much about this can be found in the books of S. Kobayashi.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not clear for me that the uniformization implies the assertion. How do you know the isometries of the quotient of the disc by a discrete subgroup of the automorphisms, maybe you are lifting something to the universal covering.

Comment: Uniformizationb+Schwarz Lemma combined imply that every automorphism is an isometry.